# jQuery .ready() bug?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a JS functions to handle it in `$(document).ready(...)`.
These functions are in file "a.js".

In function "example(TAG_ID)" I call:

```
console.log( $('#anything').children().length )
```

OK. When I include in Application Main Javascrip file: `$(document).ready(example(TAG_ID))`, is returned: `0`

But. When I include `<script>$(document).ready(example(TAG_ID))</script>` after the element whose id is TAG_ID, is returned: `7` (as it should be)

Description of jQuery.ready() function is: "Specify a function to execute when the DOM is fully loaded."

I think it is not running after the elements are fully loaded... Why?

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle that demonstrates your example? It’s kind of hard to follow.

Comment: First rule of thumb: if you think [insert hugely popular and common framework or language here] has a bug, it's probably your code. Not *always*, but usually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(example(TAG_ID))
```

evaluates `example(TAG_ID)` immediately. As the docs you quoted say, what you want to do is pass a *function* to `ready()` for it to run when the DOM is ready, which will defer the evaluation:

```
$(document).ready(function() { example(TAG_ID) })
```

Comment: +1, because IMO this can't really be said enough, apparently!

Comment: Correctly, I pass the function "example(TAG_ID)", because I want split handler and function to act as a framework. Include file "a.js", call handler function in your "main.JS" and works, that is the idea.. It is possible?

Comment: @AlexandreMagro `example(TAG_ID)` is not a function, it is the result of calling a function.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, cool! Now I understand the gap.. Here I got the answer, thanks!